# Dragons and adventure? I can't remember the title

Tags: story-identification, dragons

So I read the trilogy in the early 2000s and have been thinking back on it. The main character is named Axel. He travels from where he lives with an old wise man to the main city. On the way he figures out that he can kill a dragon with a fire arrow by shooting down its throat right before it breathes fire. That's all I remember from the first book.

One of the others has him attacked by a barbarians who have invaded the country. I think they were covered in blue paint. They end up being friends and helping each other out. Axel drops rotten eggs on the barbarians to drive them away from the castle.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/711174.Dragonslaying_is_for_Dreamers#?

Comment: Legit I just started googling the same thing trying to figure it out. I feel like it was something like "dueling with dragons" or "dealing with dragons" but Dealing with Dragons is definitely something else I think. PLEASE try to keep looking, and PLEASE someone answer.

Comment: @KayleeManning Did you follow the link that Valorum gave?  After reading the summary there and the question, I can't imagine that isn't the series you're looking for.

Comment: @Valorum can't be anything else than that. Kick that one off the Unanswered tab :)

Answer (score 3):

Could this be ***[Dragonslaying is for Dreamers](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/711174.Dragonslaying_is_for_Dreamers)*** by Dave Marks?

> In a world that never was and never will be, but as in our own world, every boy needs to be able to marry his girl, buy land and feel like a man, but this isn't always possible.
>
> The only way to be what he feels driven to be is for Axel to harvest dragons for bounty - huge and terrible beasts, which think, learn, and kill with pleasure.

The second book, ***[Axel Meets the Blue Men](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/750517.Axel_Meets_the_Blue_Men)***, features blue-painted barbarians.

> In this second book in the Dragonslayer series, the kingdom is being burnt town by town, the castle is under siege and children are being made into slaves. Axel is called back to the castle by the king to help in the defense of the kingdom from an invasion by blue-painted barbarians. He must choose between peace and war, killing and nonviolence, duty and desire, and so is torn between the peace of the valley, where he farms with his wife and son, and his duty to the king. Watch this gentle father and farmer as he struggles to fulfill his duty and still keep to his values.